# How to use is_feed() to target a category feed?

Tags: feed, conditional-tags

[`is_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) (one of the many [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)) can be used to determine if the current query is for a feed.

But how do I use it to target all category feeds? (or tag or custom taxonomy feeds for that matter)

This doesn't seem right:

```
if (is_category()) {

    if (is_feed()) {
        // Code Goes here
    }

}
```

And I have no clue as to whatelse I'd try.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Wordpress has the ability to create a feed for any and all categories, and you can link to that feed using (for instance): http://www.example.com/?cat=42&feed=rss2 (for more information on feeds, see [Wordpress Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds))

Comment: @Vivienne I'd prefer modifying the feed itself rather than use a different URL for my use-case in which I am making drastic changes to the posts displayed (and loop) for a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to customize your RSS feeds. Maybe this will help: [Customizing Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds)

Comment: @Vivienne Thanks for trying to help, but I'd done all that background work before asking the question.

Comment: OK, you never know :-). Glad @birgire could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to determine if you are in a category feed, for example:

```
 http://example.com/category/football/feed
```

you can do so with

```
add_action('wp', 'mycheck');
function mycheck() {
    if(is_feed() && is_category() ){
        // do stuff    
    }
}
```

or

```
add_action('wp', 'mycheck');
function mycheck() {
    global $wp_query;

    if($wp_query->is_feed && $wp_query->is_category){
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

You can similarly check if you are in a tag feed, for example:

```
 http://example.com/tag/liverpool/feed
```

with `is_tag`.

You can then check if you are in a custom taxonomy feed, for example:

```
 http://example.com/country/england/feed
```

with `is_tax`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. It didn't occur to me that I'd indeed use the `&&` operator

Comment: ok great, good luck with your project.

Comment: I think the `pre_get_posts` filter would be more appropriate to `set()` or `get()` the `$wp_query` values.